# solr shards as *rolling* partitions

Tags: solr, sharding

Is there a simple way to get solr to maintain shards as rolling partitions by date, e.g., the last day's documents in one shard, the week before yesterday in the next shard, the month before that in the next shard, and so on? I really don't need querying to be fast on the entire index, but it is critical that it be blazing fast on recent documents.

A related but different question: in which config file can I change the default hash function to assign documents to shards? This outdated post 
  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NewSolrCloudDesign
seems to suggest that you can define your own hash functions as well as assign hash ranges to partitions, but I am not sure whether or how solr 3.6 supports this. For that matter, I don't know whether or how SolrCloud (that I understand is available only in solr4) supports this. My goal is to have a non-uniform partitioning of documents across shards (unlike `hash(ID)%numShards`) but I need an automated way of doing this as opposed to manually assigning documents to specific shards.

Comment: This page   http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding says that the hashing to map documents to shards has to be done by yourself and solr itself does not support it. This answers my second question above. I am still looking for an answer to the first question on rolling partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that custom hashing in SolrCloud is not implemented yet, more info [SOLR-2592](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2592)